# Could not able to get image displayed in mobiles in html

Tags: html, css

I have made a website(HTML, CSS). I have placed images in some of the web pages. I've checked it in laptop and desktop. Images are getting displayed. But, in small screens it is not getting displayed even though the photos and html files are in same folder.

For images, I have used height and width as auto.

Pls help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Please share your code, so anyone can go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `px` instead  of `auto`  and make it responsive in mobile screens with [`@media`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) queries.

please follow [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask question.